# Why does a pipeline reading from and writing to the same file result in a blank file?

Tags: bash

I have a text file with some lines I'd like to sort. This file is named `somefile`.

```
cat somefile | sort
```

results in some sorted output being sent to stdout.

```
cat somefile > anotherfile
```

results in the output of `cat somefile` being written to `anotherfile`

However

```
cat somefile | sort > somefile
```

results in `somefile` being empty.

Why is this? I expect `somefile` to be sent to stdout, redirected into the sort program which sends sorted output to stdout which is then written to `somefile`.

Answer (score 2):

Processes in a pipeline are executed in parallel, not sequentially.

So what `cat somefile | sort > somefile` does is:

Concurrently run `cat` and `sort` with `cat`'s `stdout` connected to `sort`'s `stdin` and both `cat`'s `stdin` and `sort`'s `stdout` connected to file descriptors opened for `somefile`.

The shell needs to setup the redirections for `<` and `>` before `cat` and `sort` can run. In this process, it uses `open()` and `dup2()` system calls for each redirection. So `cat` does not get a chance to read from the file before the `open()` system call for the `>` truncates it.

Answer (score 0):

The `>` redirection first empties the target file, so there's nothing to cat or sort.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using only the sort command.

```
sort -o somefile somefile
```

Otherwise you will have to run your sort to a tmp file

```
sort somefile > tmpfile && mv tmpfile somefile
```